# IntelliJ IDEA crash and cause the browser out of memory

Tags: intellij-idea

I use IntelliJ IDEA 2020.1 x64 on windows10.

When IDEA was just installed, these two parameters were like this: `-Xms128m -Xmx512m`. When starting IDEA, it crashed. I checked some methods and adjusted these two parameters.

I modify `idea.exe.vmoptions` and `idea64.exe.vmoptions`.

The config in `idea.exe.vmoptions` likes this:

```
-server
-Xms500m
-Xmx6000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
```

And the config in `idea64.exe.vmoptions` likes this:

```
-Xms500m
-Xmx6000m
-XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=500m
-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC
-XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=50
-ea
-XX:CICompilerCount=2
-Dsun.io.useCanonPrefixCache=false
-Djdk.http.auth.tunneling.disabledSchemes=""
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
-XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow
-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true
-Dkotlinx.coroutines.debug=off
-Djdk.module.illegalAccess.silent=true
```

The memory of my computer is 16GB.
When I run the spring boot project, my browser often prompts out of memory, sometimes IntelliJ IDEA will crash, I tried to install the new version and the old version IntelliJ IDEA, but the problem still exists, how can I solve this problem?

The log is:

```
#
# There is insufficient memory for the Java Runtime Environment to continue.
# Native memory allocation (malloc) failed to allocate 32744 bytes for ChunkPool::allocate
# Possible reasons:
#   The system is out of physical RAM or swap space
#   In 32 bit mode, the process size limit was hit
# Possible solutions:
#   Reduce memory load on the system
#   Increase physical memory or swap space
#   Check if swap backing store is full
#   Use 64 bit Java on a 64 bit OS
#   Decrease Java heap size (-Xmx/-Xms)
#   Decrease number of Java threads
#   Decrease Java thread stack sizes (-Xss)
#   Set larger code cache with -XX:ReservedCodeCacheSize=
# This output file may be truncated or incomplete.
#
#  Out of Memory Error (allocation.cpp:273), pid=11172, tid=0x0000000000003610
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (8.0_191-b12) (build 1.8.0_191-b12)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (25.191-b12 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x000000001d1c0800):  VMThread [stack: 0x000000001ee90000,0x000000001ef90000] [id=13840]

Stack: [0x000000001ee90000,0x000000001ef90000]
[error occurred during error reporting (printing stack bounds), id 0xc0000005]

Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)

VM_Operation (0x000000002cb7e800): BulkRevokeBias, mode: safepoint, requested by thread 0x0000000023b4f000

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x0000000025d52000 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2020, stack(0x00000000312b0000,0x00000000313b0000)]
  0x0000000025d52800 JavaThread "RMI TCP Connection(10)-192.168.6.104" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=708, stack(0x00000000315b0000,0x00000000316b0000)]
  0x00000000255b9800 JavaThread "MyScheduler_Worker-3" [_thread_blocked, id=9036, stack(0x0000000028cb0000,0x0000000028db0000)]
  0x00000000255bc000 JavaThread "MyScheduler_Worker-2" [_thread_blocked, id=12700, stack(0x0000000028bb0000,0x0000000028cb0000)]
  0x00000000255bc800 JavaThread "MyScheduler_Worker-1" [_thread_blocked, id=4656, stack(0x0000000028ab0000,0x0000000028bb0000)]
  0x00000000255b4800 JavaThread "container-0" [_thread_blocked, id=13452, stack(0x00000000279b0000,0x0000000027ab0000)]
  0x00000000255b3800 JavaThread "Catalina-utility-2" [_thread_blocked, id=1992, stack(0x00000000278b0000,0x00000000279b0000)]
  0x00000000255b3000 JavaThread "Catalina-utility-1" [_thread_blocked, id=2356, stack(0x00000000277b0000,0x00000000278b0000)]
  0x0000000023b4c000 JavaThread "com.alibaba.nacos.naming.push.receiver" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=9632, stack(0x00000000276b0000,0x00000000277b0000)]
  0x0000000023b4c800 JavaThread "com.alibaba.nacos.naming.failover" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13268, stack(0x00000000275b0000,0x00000000276b0000)]
  0x0000000023b4a800 JavaThread "com.alibaba.nacos.naming.client.listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=2532, stack(0x00000000274b0000,0x00000000275b0000)]
  0x0000000023b4b000 JavaThread "logback-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12164, stack(0x00000000273b0000,0x00000000274b0000)]
  0x0000000023b50800 JavaThread "SimplePauseDetectorThread_0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13036, stack(0x00000000272b0000,0x00000000273b0000)]
  0x0000000023b4f800 JavaThread "Thread-50" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13972, stack(0x00000000271b0000,0x00000000272b0000)]
  0x0000000023b51000 JavaThread "Druid-ConnectionPool-Destroy-510868405" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9068, stack(0x00000000270b0000,0x00000000271b0000)]
  0x0000000023b4d800 JavaThread "Druid-ConnectionPool-Create-510868405" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=11316, stack(0x0000000026fb0000,0x00000000270b0000)]
  0x0000000023e99000 JavaThread "mysql-cj-abandoned-connection-cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14372, stack(0x0000000026ab0000,0x0000000026bb0000)]
  0x0000000025260800 JavaThread "CleanCursors-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=13192, stack(0x00000000264b0000,0x00000000265b0000)]
  0x00000000203cb000 JavaThread "cluster-ClusterId{value='5fd964971130802ba4672959', description='null'}-localhost:27017" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14584, stack(0x00000000263b0000,0x00000000264b0000)]
  0x00000000203c4000 JavaThread "spring.cloud.inetutils" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8896, stack(0x00000000262b0000,0x00000000263b0000)]
  0x00000000232b0800 JavaThread "lettuce-eventExecutorLoop-1-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7868, stack(0x0000000022510000,0x0000000022610000)]
  0x000000001efdc000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=14732, stack(0x000000001f590000,0x000000001f690000)]
  0x000000001d1ce000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=12328, stack(0x000000001f490000,0x000000001f590000)]
  0x000000001efb0800 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=8496, stack(0x000000001f390000,0x000000001f490000)]

Other Threads:
=>0x000000001d1c0800 VMThread [stack: 0x000000001ee90000,0x000000001ef90000] [id=13840]
  0x00000000206eb800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x0000000021860000,0x0000000021960000] [id=12316]

VM state:at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread:  ([mutex/lock_event])
[0x00000000034692c0] Threads_lock - owner thread: 0x000000001d1c0800

Heap:
 PSYoungGen      total 467456K, used 85036K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078f100000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 449536K, 18% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000077040b068,0x0000000786800000)
  from space 17920K, 0% used [0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078cd00000)
  to   space 36864K, 0% used [0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078f100000)
 ParOldGen       total 331264K, used 80939K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006d5580000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 331264K, 24% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c610ac88,0x00000006d5580000)
 Metaspace       used 95402K, capacity 100210K, committed 100480K, reserved 1136640K
  class space    used 11815K, capacity 12621K, committed 12672K, reserved 1048576K

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000012b10000,0x0000000013310000] byte_map_base: 0x000000000f507000

Marking Bits: (ParMarkBitMap*) 0x0000000077893e30
 Begin Bits: [0x0000000014060000, 0x0000000018018000)
 End Bits:   [0x0000000018018000, 0x000000001bfd0000)

Polling page: 0x0000000000df0000

CodeCache: size=245760Kb used=21399Kb max_used=21399Kb free=224360Kb
 bounds [0x0000000003750000, 0x0000000004c40000, 0x0000000012750000]
 total_blobs=11226 nmethods=10469 adapters=675
 compilation: enabled

Compilation events (10 events):
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x0000000020325800 10738       1       org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.condition.AbstractMediaTypeExpression::isNegated (5 bytes)
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x0000000020325800 nmethod 10738 0x0000000004c36b90 code [0x0000000004c36ce0, 0x0000000004c36df0]
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x0000000020325800 10732       1       io.netty.util.Recycler$WeakOrderQueue$Link::access$1300 (5 bytes)
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x0000000020325800 nmethod 10732 0x0000000004c36e50 code [0x0000000004c36fa0, 0x0000000004c37090]

GC Heap History (10 events):
Event: 36.704 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=21 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 447488K, used 428192K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078c300000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 419328K, 100% used [0x000000076b100000,0x0000000784a80000,0x0000000784a80000)
  from space 28160K, 31% used [0x0000000784a80000,0x0000000785328090,0x0000000786600000)
  to   space 27648K, 0% used [0x000000078a800000,0x000000078a800000,0x000000078c300000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 46131K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 21% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c3f0ccc0,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 66193K, capacity 68980K, committed 69120K, reserved 1110016K
  class space    used 8364K, capacity 8886K, committed 8960K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 36.715 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=21 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 510976K, used 20023K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078c200000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 484352K, 0% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b100000,0x0000000788a00000)
  from space 26624K, 75% used [0x000000078a800000,0x000000078bb8de50,0x000000078c200000)
  to   space 28672K, 0% used [0x0000000788a00000,0x0000000788a00000,0x000000078a600000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 46139K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 21% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c3f0ecc0,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 66193K, capacity 68980K, committed 69120K, reserved 1110016K
  class space    used 8364K, capacity 8886K, committed 8960K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 40.327 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=22 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 510976K, used 504375K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078c200000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 484352K, 100% used [0x000000076b100000,0x0000000788a00000,0x0000000788a00000)
  from space 26624K, 75% used [0x000000078a800000,0x000000078bb8de50,0x000000078c200000)
  to   space 28672K, 0% used [0x0000000788a00000,0x0000000788a00000,0x000000078a600000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 46139K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 21% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c3f0ecc0,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 72217K, capacity 75624K, committed 75776K, reserved 1116160K
  class space    used 9030K, capacity 9624K, committed 9728K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 40.345 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=22 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 513024K, used 28640K [0x000000076b100000, 0x0000000791280000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 484352K, 0% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b100000,0x0000000788a00000)
  from space 28672K, 99% used [0x0000000788a00000,0x000000078a5f8150,0x000000078a600000)
  to   space 34816K, 0% used [0x000000078f080000,0x000000078f080000,0x0000000791280000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 51466K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 23% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c44429d8,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 72217K, capacity 75624K, committed 75776K, reserved 1116160K
  class space    used 9030K, capacity 9624K, committed 9728K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 307.904 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 513024K, used 512992K [0x000000076b100000, 0x0000000791280000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 484352K, 100% used [0x000000076b100000,0x0000000788a00000,0x0000000788a00000)
  from space 28672K, 99% used [0x0000000788a00000,0x000000078a5f8150,0x000000078a600000)
  to   space 34816K, 0% used [0x000000078f080000,0x000000078f080000,0x0000000791280000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 51466K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 23% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c44429d8,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 86776K, capacity 90974K, committed 91264K, reserved 1128448K
  class space    used 10880K, capacity 11585K, committed 11648K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 307.932 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=23 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 501248K, used 34804K [0x000000076b100000, 0x0000000791280000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 466432K, 0% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b100000,0x0000000787880000)
  from space 34816K, 99% used [0x000000078f080000,0x000000079127d260,0x0000000791280000)
  to   space 44544K, 0% used [0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078e700000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 62821K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 29% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c4f59600,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 86776K, capacity 90974K, committed 91264K, reserved 1128448K
  class space    used 10880K, capacity 11585K, committed 11648K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 324.558 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=24 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 501248K, used 164111K [0x000000076b100000, 0x0000000791280000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 466432K, 27% used [0x000000076b100000,0x0000000772f46c98,0x0000000787880000)
  from space 34816K, 99% used [0x000000078f080000,0x000000079127d260,0x0000000791280000)
  to   space 44544K, 0% used [0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078e700000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 62821K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 29% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c4f59600,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 93677K, capacity 98290K, committed 98380K, reserved 1134592K
  class space    used 11664K, capacity 12457K, committed 12544K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 324.583 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=24 (full 3):
 PSYoungGen      total 467456K, used 17577K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078f100000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 449536K, 0% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b100000,0x0000000786800000)
  from space 17920K, 98% used [0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078ccaa4b0,0x000000078cd00000)
  to   space 36864K, 0% used [0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078f100000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 82841K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 38% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c62e67c0,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 93677K, capacity 98290K, committed 98380K, reserved 1134592K
  class space    used 11664K, capacity 12457K, committed 12544K, reserved 1048576K
}
Event: 324.583 GC heap before
{Heap before GC invocations=25 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 467456K, used 17577K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078f100000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 449536K, 0% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b100000,0x0000000786800000)
  from space 17920K, 98% used [0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078ccaa4b0,0x000000078cd00000)
  to   space 36864K, 0% used [0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078f100000)
 ParOldGen       total 216064K, used 82841K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006ce500000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 216064K, 38% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c62e67c0,0x00000006ce500000)
 Metaspace       used 93677K, capacity 98290K, committed 98380K, reserved 1134592K
  class space    used 11664K, capacity 12457K, committed 12544K, reserved 1048576K
Event: 324.830 GC heap after
Heap after GC invocations=25 (full 4):
 PSYoungGen      total 467456K, used 0K [0x000000076b100000, 0x000000078f100000, 0x00000007c0000000)
  eden space 449536K, 0% used [0x000000076b100000,0x000000076b100000,0x0000000786800000)
  from space 17920K, 0% used [0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078bb80000,0x000000078cd00000)
  to   space 36864K, 0% used [0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078cd00000,0x000000078f100000)
 ParOldGen       total 331264K, used 80939K [0x00000006c1200000, 0x00000006d5580000, 0x000000076b100000)
  object space 331264K, 24% used [0x00000006c1200000,0x00000006c610ac88,0x00000006d5580000)
 Metaspace       used 93672K, capacity 98276K, committed 98380K, reserved 1134592K
  class space    used 11663K, capacity 12454K, committed 12544K, reserved 1048576K
}

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Classes redefined (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (10 events):
Event: 356.677 Thread 0x000000002591a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x0000000770068910) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.677 Thread 0x000000002591e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076ddd7678) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.677 Thread 0x0000000025919000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076cfc0370) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.677 Thread 0x000000002591d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076bbecc98) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.695 Thread 0x000000002591e800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076ddebac8) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.695 Thread 0x0000000025919000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076cfd3988) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.695 Thread 0x000000002591a800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000077007cd70) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.695 Thread 0x0000000025918800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076ff1cc80) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.695 Thread 0x000000002591a000 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076ffce800) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]
Event: 356.695 Thread 0x000000002591d800 Exception <a 'java/lang/ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException'> (0x000000076bc05988) thrown at [C:\re\workspace\8-2-build-windows-amd64-cygwin\jdk8u191\11896\hotspot\src\share\vm\runtime\sharedRuntime.cpp, line 605]

Events (10 events):
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000003797890 sp=0x000000002bb79ea8 mode 1
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003e5454c sp=0x000000002bb7a2b0
Event: 356.698 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000003797890 sp=0x000000002bb79fd0 mode 1
Event: 356.700 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003d07eb4 sp=0x000000002bb79fb0
Event: 356.700 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000003797890 sp=0x000000002bb79ea8 mode 1
Event: 356.700 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT PACKING pc=0x0000000003e5454c sp=0x000000002bb7a2b0
Event: 356.700 Thread 0x000000002591a800 DEOPT UNPACKING pc=0x0000000003797890 sp=0x000000002bb79fd0 mode 1
Event: 356.701 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias
Event: 356.702 Executing VM operation: RevokeBias done
Event: 356.702 Executing VM operation: BulkRevokeBias


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6b22c0000 - 0x00007ff6b22f7000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\bin\java.exe
0x00007ff8baca0000 - 0x00007ff8bae90000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff8b92c0000 - 0x00007ff8b9372000     C:\Windows\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff8a7d70000 - 0x00007ff8a7ff5000     C:\Windows\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.18362.53_none_a1435cd8519dc9c0\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff8ba190000 - 0x00007ff8ba4c6000     C:\Windows\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff8b8ca0000 - 0x00007ff8b8d21000     C:\Windows\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff8b99c0000 - 0x00007ff8b99ee000     C:\Windows\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000077a10000 - 0x0000000077ae2000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x0000000077070000 - 0x0000000077914000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff8b9780000 - 0x00007ff8b9788000     C:\Windows\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff8a2d50000 - 0x00007ff8a2d59000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff8b17d0000 - 0x00007ff8b17da000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\VERSION.dll
0x00007ff8b5880000 - 0x00007ff8b58a4000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff8b98a0000 - 0x00007ff8b990f000     C:\Windows\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff8b5840000 - 0x00007ff8b586d000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\winmmbase.dll
0x00007ff8b83d0000 - 0x00007ff8b841a000     C:\Windows\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000076f80000 - 0x0000000076f8f000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000076f50000 - 0x0000000076f79000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\java.dll
0x0000000077ba0000 - 0x0000000077bd5000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\jdwp.dll
0x0000000077b90000 - 0x0000000077b98000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\npt.dll
0x0000000077b60000 - 0x0000000077b83000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\instrument.dll
0x0000000076f30000 - 0x0000000076f46000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff8ba4d0000 - 0x00007ff8babb0000     C:\Windows\System32\SHELL32.dll
0x00007ff8b97f0000 - 0x00007ff8b9899000     C:\Windows\System32\shcore.dll
0x00007ff8b7c50000 - 0x00007ff8b83cb000     C:\Windows\System32\windows.storage.dll
0x00007ff8b7bf0000 - 0x00007ff8b7c0f000     C:\Windows\System32\profapi.dll
0x00007ff8b7b80000 - 0x00007ff8b7bca000     C:\Windows\System32\powrprof.dll
0x00007ff8b7b70000 - 0x00007ff8b7b80000     C:\Windows\System32\UMPDC.dll
0x00007ff8b9380000 - 0x00007ff8b93d2000     C:\Windows\System32\shlwapi.dll
0x00007ff8b7bd0000 - 0x00007ff8b7be1000     C:\Windows\System32\kernel.appcore.dll
0x00007ff8b7c30000 - 0x00007ff8b7c47000     C:\Windows\System32\cryptsp.dll
0x0000000077b50000 - 0x0000000077b59000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\dt_socket.dll
0x00007ff8b73e0000 - 0x00007ff8b7447000     C:\Windows\system32\mswsock.dll
0x0000000076f00000 - 0x0000000076f1a000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\net.dll
0x00007ff8b7180000 - 0x00007ff8b724a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\DNSAPI.dll
0x00007ff8b96f0000 - 0x00007ff8b96f8000     C:\Windows\System32\NSI.dll
0x00007ff8b7140000 - 0x00007ff8b717a000     C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\IPHLPAPI.DLL
0x00007ff8aacb0000 - 0x00007ff8aacba000     C:\Windows\System32\rasadhlp.dll
0x00007ff8ada40000 - 0x00007ff8adab7000     C:\Windows\System32\fwpuclnt.dll
0x00007ff8b8d30000 - 0x00007ff8b8d56000     C:\Windows\System32\bcrypt.dll
0x0000000076f20000 - 0x0000000076f2d000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\management.dll
0x0000000076ee0000 - 0x0000000076ef1000     C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_191\jre\bin\nio.dll
0x00007ff8b6fa0000 - 0x00007ff8b6fd3000     C:\Windows\system32\rsaenh.dll
```

Comment: the out of memory issue is caused by your browser or Intellij IDEA? Please include the log for easy debugging. You can find it from `Help` ->`Show Log in Explorer`

Comment: As you said,I can see `Increase physical memory or swap space` in log,but in fact my computer has 16GB memory.I think this is enough.

Comment: Are you running any application inside IDEA? It doesn't seem like it is caused by IDEA but more related to the application that your start inside IDEA.

Comment: Yes,I run three spring boot project inside IDEA.

Comment: It could the springboot app that your run caused the OOME, by increasing the memory inside IDEA will not help. Instead, you need to increase the memory for your springboot app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I know the reason.

The size of the virtual memory was `0MB` before.

I increased the size of the virtual memory on the `C` disk. I set the virtual memory size to `2GB`.

Then I restarted the computer, and when I ran IDEA again, the browser no longer had problems.

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from what process do you get the OOM error? From IDEA or other? Where do you see this error? You say you see it after you launch Spring Boot configuration? Then this is not related to IDEA's `*.vmoptions` and IDE's own process. You need to increase the -Xmx for the process that you launch for your [Spring Boot application](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-spring-boot.html) configuration. You can set the `-Xmx` in **VM options** field.

Comment: Hi,I think it is caused by IDEA, because I did not start other things.

Comment: It is still unclear where and after what actions do you see this error. Please attach screenshots.